# Javascript: Arrays built during for loop have their order reset

Tags: javascript, arrays

This code seems straightforward enough

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
let store = [];

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  console.log(arr)
  store.push(arr)
  arr.push(arr.shift())
}
console.log('store', JSON.stringify(store))
```

I'm expecting it to return

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,3,4,5,6,1],[3,4,5,6,1,2],[4,5,6,1,2,3],[5,6,1,2,3,4],[6,1,2,3,4,5]]
```

But when the loop is complete, it shows

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

When printing the values in the console, they appear correct, but when the store variable is logged, they are all reordered.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
[5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Why is this occurring?

There is a similar question here, but it doesn't really provide an answer for my case.

[Creating a pair of arrays from an array resulting in circular array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436341/creating-a-pair-of-arrays-from-an-array-resulting-in-circular-array)

Comment: You keep mutating `arr`, and `store` just contains multiple references to *the same array object*.

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure you are inserting **not** the same reference to your array:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
let store = [];

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  store.push(Array.from(arr))  // <-- Make sure not the same ref
  arr.push(arr.shift())
}
console.log('store', JSON.stringify(store))
```

Answer (score 1):

`store` contains the same instance of `arr` 6 times. You modify it and print it every time, then add the same object to `store`, then modify it again.

To get your desired behaviour you need to add a new instance every time e.g. by cloning it when you add it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks George.

Answer (score 1):

You could push a copy which does not keep the same object reference.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
let store = [];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  store.push(arr.slice())                // just take a copy
  arr.push(arr.shift())
}
console.log(store.map(a => a.join(' ')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate approach leaving original array untouched and using `splice()` to remove beginning elements and `concat()` to add to the end

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

let store = arr.map((_,i)=> {
   let a = arr.slice();
   return i ? a.concat(a.splice(0,i)) : a;
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(store))
```

Answer (score 1):

On every loop, you are pushing the reference of the array to store

Example:
Loop - reference of arr - 0x112, then store[ i ] = reference to 0x112

At end:
arr - refer to 0x112 - value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

store[ ] = [ref(0x112), ref(0x112), ref(0x112), ref(0x112), ref(0x112), ref(0x112)]

Use this:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
let store = [];

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  console.log(arr)
  let newArr = arr.slice();
  store.push(newArr)  
  arr.push(arr.shift())
}
console.log('store', JSON.stringify(store))
```